# How to integrate msys2 console in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, msys2

So what I would need to do is having the console of msys2 for ESP32 controller inside the VS Studio, for the sake of less windows opened, and the less time required to change between them. This will help me to focus both on the explorer code and terminal in the same time.
The reason why I use msys2 over cmd, is the version of esp-idf. I need the version V3.3 for a project.

[image]
(*founded [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/windows-setup.html#introduction)*)

The code what I ended up with is this, in the `blink.code-workspace` file :

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "D:\\esp\\msys2\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe",
        "terminal.integrated.env.windows":
        {
            "MSYSTEM": "MINGW64",
            //"MSYS2_PATH_TYPE": "inherit",
            "MSVSCODE": "1"
        },
        "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
            "/k",
            "D:/esp/esp-idf/export.bat"
        ]
    }
}
```

The first 2 rows integrate msys2 into the VSCode, which it works (just in terminal, without tasks).

The third row it brings `IDF_PATH` to the console, but only on cmd console (4.1 esp-idf verssion). I need  somehow to bring `IDF_PATH` or `idf.py` by msys2 console into vscode (V3.3 is what I use).
Hope it make sense.

After almost 2 weeks of intense searching and researching I wounder, is this even possible ?

Comment: If working with ESP IDF v3.3, it makes sense to use the [documentation for v3.3](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v3.3.4/get-started/windows-setup.html), if you haven't already.

Comment: is nothing in the documentation about how to setup the vscode.